# Download tile layers for use offline

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, layers, tiles, offline

I would like to download tile layers in this form:

```
{atlas_name}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

Because I want to use them offline with my leaflet map.

However, I can't find what are the approaches to download such tiles for offline use? Are there some apps for this?

Comment: How many tiles are we talking about? What's the geographic extent, the zoom levels? Techniques differ depending on that.

Comment: forgot to sign up, so posting from this account. geographic area is *country*: georgia. zoom levels, let's say: 16,17,18

Comment: Does the tile provider allow this kind of usage?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I don't have some specific tile provider.

Comment: @bugmenot123 any "decent" looking maps would to

Comment: Just for your info: zoom level 18 means 68.719.476.736 tiles (if map is square), and each tile should be about 5KB to 25KB.

Comment: @TomazicM Yes I managed to download tile layers for this country for zoom level 14 and size is 200MB which is already not small. What other approach can one take, to have smaller size of offline layers (or offline cache), assuming I need to use leaflet.js?

Comment: You can try `TileLayer.PouchDBCached` plugin: https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached

Comment: @TomazicM Will that occupy less space than downloading tile layer .pngs manually for a certain zoom and area?

Comment: No, this is just an offline cache. There is no way to reduce size of tiles without loosing quality.

Comment: @TomazicM Ah so it might take less space only if say user cached few images from the map using this plugin? as opposed to caching all pngs as I am doing now? thanks. (Because mainly I have size problem, caching problem I solved using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608919/html-offline-map-with-local-tiles-via-leaflet)

Answer (score 2):

This golang script works like a charm for downloading tiles from WMS servers: https://github.com/Luqqk/wms-tiles-downloader.

To do it in the browser: https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached as mentioned by https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm  (@TomazicM)

Answer (score 1):

I created this script in Python, which helped me a lot. Fill in the parameters according to your constraints. I used Thunderforest as a provider. You have to register to get the api_key and then choose the style you want. There is a free version for several requests per month. Feel free to change the URL and use other providers.

```py
import requests
import os
import time

# Define the URL pattern for the Thunderforest Transport Map tile layer
# FILL map_style and api_key
url_pattern = "https://tile.thunderforest.com/<map_style>/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=<your_api_key>"

# Define the maximum zoom level to retrieve tiles for
max_zoom = 7

# Define the output directory for the downloaded tiles
output_dir = "tiles"

# time in seconds between requests to don't overload the provider
sleep_time = 0.2

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

# Loop over each zoom level up to the maximum zoom level
for zoom in range(max_zoom + 1):
    # Calculate the number of tiles in the x and y directions at the current zoom level
    num_tiles = 2**zoom

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(output_dir, str(zoom))):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(output_dir, str(zoom)))

    # Loop over each tile in the x and y directions
    for x in range(num_tiles):

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(output_dir, str(zoom), str(x))):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(output_dir, str(zoom), str(x)))

        for y in range( num_tiles):
            # Construct the URL for the current tile
            url = url_pattern.format(z=zoom, x=x, y=y)

            # Send a request to download the tile
            response = requests.get(url)

            # Save the tile to the output directory
            filename = os.path.join(
                os.path.join(output_dir, str(zoom), str(x)), f"{y}.png"
            )
            with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                f.write(response.content)

            # Print a message to indicate progress
            print(f"Downloaded tile {zoom}/{x}/{y}")
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

This is useful for downloading the entire map at a specific zoom level. To give you an estimate, you will download 100Mb of data till Zoom 7, and you will get double the size for the next Zoom level. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**sas.planet is my favorite tool. You will use it forever.**

for more info : SAS.Team SAS SAS.Planet

https://php-full-stack.blogspot.com/2019/06/sasteam-sas-sasplanetbin.html

Comment: can you add some more information to your answer as links may get offline.

Comment: You need to install it on an online computer to get the tiles downloaded in the installation sub directory.Then copy that directory in an offline computer to use them offline with leaflet map.

Comment: Please let me know if you succeded to do it :)